# Why does Set allow a duplicate here?

Tags: java, set, hashset

I have the code below:

```
class Animal {
    int i;

    public Animal(){
        i=13;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Animal "+i;
    }
}
//
public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet hs=new HashSet();
        boolean b=hs.add(new Animal());
        boolean b1=hs.add(new Animal());
        System.out.println(b+" "+b1);
        for(Object o:hs)
        {
            System.out.println(hs);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that `Set` does not allow duplicates, but why does the above code seem to allow two identical values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As has already been pointed out, you need to override `hashCode` and `equals`. You can compare on the `int i` with something like,

```
class Animal {
    int i;

    public Animal() {
        i = 13;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal " + i;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Integer.hashCode(i);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Animal) {
            return ((Animal) obj).i == i;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I would suggest you use generics with your `Collection`. Also, you should print the instance (not the `Collection`) in your loop. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Animal> hs = new HashSet<>();
    boolean b = hs.add(new Animal());
    boolean b1 = hs.add(new Animal());
    System.out.println(b + " " + b1);
    for (Animal a : hs) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

And I get (the expected)

```
true false
Animal 13
```

Answer (score 7):

Because Java has no way of knowing that your two instances are the same.

You need to override `equals()` *and `hashcode()`*
.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't overridden `hashcode` and `equals` in the `Animal` class.  Therefore, these methods are inherited from `java.lang.Object`.

The inherited behaviour (from `Object`) is that objects are only equal if they are the same object.

In this case, a suitable pair of overrides for `equals` and `hashcode` would be something like this:

```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
      return other instanceof Animal && 
             other != null &&
             ((Animal) other).i == this.i;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return i;
  }
```

(Note that if you start creating subclasses of `Animal`, you need to think carefully on how best to implement `equals(Object)`.  By code above doesn't attempt to deal with that ...)

Comment: This code also get the same result. mistake at hashcode() method.Thanks for good idea

Comment: There is no mistake in the hashcode method.  Please explain.

Comment: There is a typo in the signature, it should be `hashCode` (camel case) instead.